# Comparing one element of an array with whole another array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

First, I created 2 arrays. Call them `A[]` and `B[]`.

Array A has elements `A = { 11, 16, 21 }`

Array B has elements `B = { 12, 7, 18, 24, 101 }`

I made a loop. Which compares both.

```
for (int i = 0; i<Acount; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Bcount; ++j) {
        if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
            total = B[j] + total;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This one compares them and if `A[]` element is smaller than any `B[]` element, loop stops and adds up B's value to the total at that point and stops comparing.

Now, if A's every element are bigger than B, for example:
`A = { 11 }` and `B = { 3, 5 }`
it should say ERROR and shouldn't show any value (as variable total), but whatever I tried it's always printing either lots of "ERROR" text or the value or even both at the same time.

What do I do?

Edit: To clarify;

Example input:

```
3 5 //these sets the sizes of A and B, respectively.
11
16
21  //these are for A.
12
7
18
24
101 //these are for B.
```

The program should do:
Hey, it's cool there's 11. Let me compare 11 from A with 12,7,18,24,101 from B and see if there's anything bigger than me. There's 12! That's nice. Let's add 12 to the total. Now, I have 16, let's do the same comparison with 12,7,18,24,101. 12 is smaller than me... so I should skip it. 7 as well... 18 is bigger than me! Let's add 18 to the total as well! Now for 21... same comparison same stuff. There's 24. Add up all and print the result.

Now, there's another example input:

```
1 2 //these sets the size of A and B, respectively.
10 // this is for A
3
5 // these are for B
```

Code should do the very same, but this time...
I have 10, let's see if anything is bigger than me. Is 10 bigger than 3? No? Is 5 bigger than 10? Obviously not. So... there's nothing bigger than me... I should print an ERROR.

I hope I made it simpler.
Cheers.

Edit 2: Here is my full code. Try it yourself with the example inputs I provided above and tell me what's wrong. First input should've printed an actual number result but prints ERROR as an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int amountA, amountB, i = 0 ,j = 0, total = 0;
    int A[20000];
    int B[20000];
    cin >> amountA >> amountB;
    for (i = 0; i < amountA; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < amountB; j++) {
        cin >> B[j];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < amountA; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < amountB; ++j) {
            if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
                total = B[j] + total;
                break;
            } else {
                cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << total << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is a little confusing, could you please add some sample input and expected output so we can have something to test against?

Comment: Sure, I'll do it.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code that performs the output printing "ERROR" and result. This looks fine without further context.

Comment: @user1320881 done!

Comment: @GhostCat how do I fix it? When I remove return 0; it prints ERROR!ERROR!ERROR!ERROR!ERROR!54

It shouldn't say any ERROR!...

Comment: @GhostCat the code that you provided gave an output of ERROR!ERROR!30 to me, it should just print out a 54 without any other messages. Anyway... thanks for trying to help.

Comment: One more try; although I am not sure; probably I am simply up too long by now. YOu need another break to only print error once. But I now that looks strange; as the inner loop will always break immediately. Something is still wrong there ...

Comment: @GhostCat exactly! Something is super fishy... this time the output was ERROR!12 we're getting there, I feel like.

Comment: I am sorry, I give up now; getting too late. But the Thing is: actually debugging such things is super-easy. Just put print statements in all the places, and **observe** what your code is doing. Or even better: take a piece of paper and "run" your program manually, without a computer. Probably we are both staring at this **simple** problem too long for now. Just stop for today; and tomorrow morning it might come "ah, its that easy" to you.

Answer (score 1):

This could get fixed with an if-else statement. If it's smaller execute the sum and the break, but if it's bigger you can set an else condition. There's an example below ;)

```
for (int i = 0; i<Acount; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Bcount; ++j)
    {
        if (A[i] <= B[j])
        {
            total = B[j] + total;
            break;
        } else {
           std::cout<<"Error"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If you still can't figure it out, below is the solution ;)

[Spoiler solution](http://pastebin.com/S78YLQ4e)

Comment: I did the very same but result is very upsetting. I posted my whole code above. Oddly it prints ERROR even if the input that I provided should've printed a number!

Comment: Great that you could provide helpful input to him ... nice answer.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman try to remove the return 0 from the else {} because it will exit the console. After testing it with you example I got 'error' like 4 times and 54.

Comment: @RazvanAlex I removed the return 0, as you said it gave ERROR!ERROR!ERROR!ERROR!ERROR!54. There shouldn't be any errors, it should simply say 54, and for my 2nd input example, it should simply say ERROR one time without any numbers or else around. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First of all tell me exactly what should be the input of this 3 5 //these sets the sizes of A and B, respectively.
11
16
21  //these are for A.
12
7
18
24
101 //these are for B.

Comment: @RazvanAlex 3 and 5 sets the sizes of array A and B. Array A should include 11 16 and 21 as elements. Meanwhile, Array B should include 12 7 18 24 101 as elements.

You can simply copy paste my code and enter the input as:
3 5
11
16
21
12
7
18
24
101

it'll show you what's wrong.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman check my edit. I provided the solution if you still can't solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

As this is possible some homework; just some thoughts to get you going:

You need some boolean *marker* variable that indicates: "A values are **all** bigger than B values".

Initially, that thing is **true**.

And within your if-then case, you simply change it to **false**.

And when you then check it after the loop: if the marker is still true; you know that all As are actually >= than the Bs. If the marker is false, there was at least one A smaller ...

Your problem with your **current** code is simply: you have a **return** statement in your else block. This means: you end your **whole** program when you get into that condition!

As said; you need a marker:

```
bool hitError = false;

for (int i = 0; i< amountA; ++i) 
{
  if (hitError) {
  break;
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < amountB; ++j)
  {
    if (A[i] <= B[j])
    {
        total = B[j] + total;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
        hitError = true;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not a homework. I'm learning C++ as a newcomer and found some exercises to teach myself. Yet... my program doesn't work properly. Let me actually post my code here and show you guys what's wrong.